# How to know the specific list on jQuery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, hover

I have this hover event in jQuery.
There's a number of `<li>` tag here

```
$("ul#mainnav li").hover(function(){
   if($(this) == $("ul#mainnav li:eq(1)")){
      alert("yes");
   } else {
      alert("no");
   }
})
```

This doesn't work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you only want to know the first? Or the position of the hover element in the list?

Comment: that's it.. not only the first. ty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to know the index of the element the event was triggered from you can do

```
index = $("#mainnav li").index(this);
if (index == 1)...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**$().is()**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) for comparision

Comment: Kind of shooting in the dark there without knowing the spec. What if the list has 20 elements? You going to *is* each one?

Comment: Which 20 elements? `this` will be 1 element and `$("ul#mainnav li:eq(1)")` will also contain 1 element (when the ul is not nested)

Comment: Read the spec + comments. Using `is()` *is not* the appropriate solution in this case.

Comment: So please explain the issue when using `if($("ul#mainnav li:eq(1)").is(this))`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to target a specific `li`, then I think this would probably work

```
$("ul#mainnav li:eq(1)").hover(function(){
   //other code
});
```

This targets the second `li` in the `#mainnav ul` and sets the hover on it.

Was that what you wanted?

**EDIT**

Given the explanation

> whenever a user hovers a list, jquery will know the eq value of it

you could do something like this

```
$('#mainnav li').mouseover(function(){
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/pUacJ/

Comment: whenever a user hovers a list, jquery will know the eq value of it

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to bind a function to the first child, this may be what you are looking for.

```
$("ul#mainnav li:first-child").hover(function(){
   //code here
});
```

more examples can be found here.
[the first-child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)